# 'Package 'nodejs' is not installed, so not removed' Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm

I want to uninstall nodejs and npm from my Ubuntu 18.04 system.
I have tried the following command.

`sudo apt purge nodejs`

**Output**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'nodejs' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 123 not upgraded.
```

**P.S.**
`which node` outputs `/usr/bin/node`

How can I uninstall nodejs and npm?